# Ostream& operator<< overloading code not working

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

class Dummy {
  private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
  public:
    Dummy(int an_age) {age = an_age;}
    bool operator> (Dummy &a) {return age > a.age;}
    std::string toString() const {return "The age is " + age;}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Dummy& d) {return out<< d.toString();}

int main()
{

  std::cout << max(3, 7) << std::endl;

  std::cout << max(3.0, 7.0) << std::endl;

  std::cout << max<int>(3, 7.0) << std::endl;

  std::cout << max("hello", "hi") << std::endl;

  Dummy d1(10);
  Dummy d2(20);
  std::cout << max(&d1, &d2) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new to C++ but not new to programming. I've written the code to play with template and operator overloading in C++.

It took quite a while to make it compile and partially work.

1. The ostream operator<< is not working properly, only to return the address of the object. I can't figure out the causes.
2. I managed to make it compile by blind trial and error, so I suspect the code might be broken to some extent. And I may not be aware of what'd be improved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `max(&d1,&d2)` expression gives you the **address**, and that is printed out. Your operator overloading is fine.

Comment: also, `"The age is " + age` will NOT do what you want.  You want to use std::ostringstream.

Comment: Yes, `max("hello", "hi")` is wrong too. OP should read up on C++ built-in types.

Comment: @Tim or just `string::operator+` for this simple case

Comment: @Seth, `std::string` does not have an `operator+(int)`

Comment: `std::string::operator+(int)` is not called in here at all. What is called is `operator+(const char*,int)` followed by `std::string(const char*)`.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: While concatenating strings together isn't particularly efficient, I think C++ should have some sort of support for this outside of `::std::ostringstream`. A `::std::to_string` template or something that can be overloaded for various types would not go amiss. It's certainly a heck of a lot better than the equally inefficient (and downright stupid) `::std::endl` that everybody persists in using.

Comment: `std::string` is already a monster, some other facility is needed, like `boost::format` or something.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the line you're talking about is

```
std::cout << max(&d1, &d2) << std::endl;
```

The problem is you are passing `Dummy *` instead of `Dummy`. That makes `max` return `Dummy *`, and since your overloaded `operator<<` takes (essentially) `Dummy`, it isn't invoked. If you're trying to pass by reference, you don't need to do anything special on the caller side, just make the function take a reference and the compiler will figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't write your own `max`, use the standard one instead:

   ```
   #include <algorithm>
   void f() { int a = std::max(8, 4); }
   ```

   The only difference is that the standard `max` uses `operator <` by default, just like everything else in the standard library.
2. Your `toString` function does something different from what you think it does. It instead returns the sub string of `"The age is "` starting at the character number `age`. For example if `age` is 3, `toString` will return `" age is "`. To convert the integer to string you have to use `ostringstream`:

   ```
   std::string toString() const { 
       std::ostringstream s;
       s << "The age is " << age; 
       return s.str();
   }
   ```

Comment: `std::max` is avoiding unnecessary copies as well (passing by reference vs copying)